# If you bet on something unenforceable does it still happen some how?

Tags: logic

So let's say a person was lying and said "I bet on my life." This is just a theory to determine if I should ever consider lying and doing this at the same time; but would you actually die early or get killed if you did this? Or is it just fake? That is my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are worried that betting on your life might cause you to die somehow through some kind of supernatural means.

This is just your personal superstition at work. You will not magically die because of your bluff. However, if you bet on your life to someone that might decide to extract revenge on you, there is the possibility that they might try to make you pay your self proclaimed stakes.

This bet might be OK in casual circumstances with friends, but don't verbalize it inside of any crime rings.

Comment: The (bad) incentives produced by over-insuring oneself with life insurance also come to mind...